# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.Readable.readArray([B)V

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

We started getting below exception while we upgraded spring-kafka to 2.8.9 and kafka-clients to 3.0.1. Please suggest.

````
laris-default-group-id] Request joining group due to: consumer pro-actively leaving the group
2022-11-04--16-41-17-047 [T: U: D: Tx:/ URI: M:] [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#9-0-C-1] ERROR org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer - Stopping container due to an Error
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.Readable.readArray([B)V
    at org.apache.kafka.common.message.SyncGroupResponseData.read(SyncGroupResponseData.java:173)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.message.SyncGroupResponseData.<init>(SyncGroupResponseData.java:102)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.requests.SyncGroupResponse.parse(SyncGroupResponse.java:61)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.requests.AbstractResponse.parseResponse(AbstractResponse.java:135)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.requests.AbstractResponse.parseResponse(AbstractResponse.java:109)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.parseResponse(NetworkClient.java:720)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.handleCompletedReceives(NetworkClient.java:865)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:560)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:265)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:236)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:215)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.joinGroupIfNeeded(AbstractCoordinator.java:427)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:366)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:511)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateAssignmentMetadataIfNeeded(KafkaConsumer.java:1262)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1233)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1166)
    at brave.kafka.clients.TracingConsumer.poll(TracingConsumer.java:93)
    at brave.kafka.clients.TracingConsumer.poll(TracingConsumer.java:87)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollConsumer(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1529)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doPoll(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1519)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1343)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1255)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)```
````

Comment: Please show your pom/Gradle dependencies. Don't upgrade kafka-clients separately from spring-kafka

Comment: According to your stack trace, you also need to see which Brave library is compatible with an Apache Kafka client you are upgrading to: ` brave.kafka.clients.TracingConsumer`. Nothing to do with Spring for Apache Kafka though.

Comment: It got resolved as suggested by Artem, brave library was creating problem. Thank you !!